# Play framework POST new twice, result in 2 identical objects

Tags: playframework-2.0, save, data-synchronization, bad-request

I have a problem with our registry using Play 2. 
The registry is a disease registry which store Patient data. Each patient has a one-to-one relation to a diagnosis class. 
Everything was fine. But occasionally I found out that diagnosis had been created twice in our database. When I looked into the access_log, I found the following thing...

> //Access patient(2) page
>
> 194.176.xxx.xxx - - [03/Oct/2014:00:09:16 +1000] "GET /npd/npc/patient/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 11470
>
> //Access diagnosis update page for patient(2), diagosis does not exist, redirect to diagnosis create
>
> 194.176.xxx.xxx - - [03/Oct/2014:00:09:44 +1000] "GET /npd/npc/diagnosis/2/update HTTP/1.1" 303 -
>
> //Access diagnosis create page for patient(2)
>
> 194.176.xxx.xxx - - [03/Oct/2014:00:09:45 +1000] "GET /npd/npc/diagnosis/new/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 69806
>
> //Attempt to save diagnosis, receive bad request
>
> 194.176.xxx.xxx - - [03/Oct/2014:00:12:56 +1000] "POST /npd/npc/diagnosis/new/2 HTTP/1.1" 400 55909
>
> 194.176.xxx.xxx - - [03/Oct/2014:00:12:56 +1000] "POST /npd/npc/diagnosis/new/2 HTTP/1.1" 400 70198
>
> //Successflly stored diagnosis, redirect to view page
>
> 194.176.xxx.xxx - - [03/Oct/2014:00:13:11 +1000] "POST /npd/npc/diagnosis/new/2 HTTP/1.1" 303 -
>
> 194.176.xxx.xxx - - [03/Oct/2014:00:13:11 +1000] "POST /npd/npc/diagnosis/new/2 HTTP/1.1" 303 -
>
> //Access diagnosis view page
>
> 194.176.xxx.xxx - - [03/Oct/2014:00:13:13 +1000] "GET /npd/npc/diagnosis/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 11925

For some reason, save diagnosis received a bad request twice (I would assume it's something on the client side, maybe their browser was hacked or whatever). But my controller has a check to see if diagnosis exist. Below is my save method

```
public static Result save(long patientId) {
    Patient patient = Ebean.find(Patient.class, patientId);

    if (patient == null) {
        flash("error", "Patient does not exist.");
        return PatientController.home();
    }

    if (patient.getDiagnosis() != null) {
        return redirect(routes.DiagnosisController.view(patientId));
    }

    Form<Diagnosis> form = form(Diagnosis.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (form.hasErrors()) {
        form.reject("Diagnosis has not been created");
        return badRequest(create.render(patient, form));
    }

    Diagnosis obj = form.get();
    obj.setPatient(patient);

    if (!form.hasErrors()) {
        // Add soft validation errors to the form
        for (Entry<String, String> e : obj.getSoftValidationErrors().entrySet()) {
            form.reject(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
        if (form.hasErrors()) {
            form.reject("Diagnosis has not been created");
            return badRequest(create.render(patient, form));
        }
    }

    obj.save();
    audit.logCreate(obj.getId(), obj);
    return redirect(routes.DiagnosisController.view(patientId));
}
```

I'm not sure why would it create diagnosis twice, maybe some synchronization problem? need help!!

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is the check for an existing diagnosis object:

```
if (patient.getDiagnosis() != null) {
    return redirect(routes.DiagnosisController.view(patientId));
}
```

And this is the code that creates and inserts the new diagnosis object:

```
Diagnosis obj = form.get();
...
obj.save();
```

What's happening is that the two POST requests are executing concurrently. Your code runs the requests at the same time in two different threads. Both threads run the check to see if the diagnosis is there and both find that it isn't there. Then both threads save a new diagnosis object to the database.

This is called a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and it is caused because both threads are reading and writing the same object concurrently. You can make your code working by using a [database transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) to group the diagnosis check and the diagnosis creation code together into one unit of work.

For more information about using transactions with Ebean in Play see *Transactional Actions* here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaEbean

Comment: Thanks, I', just wonder what's the difference between synchronizing the method block and using the transactional annotation?

Comment: That mean that only one thread could call `save` at a time, which would kill your application's performance.

If your application needs to be reliable in how it treats its data—for example, if you're working with patient data—then you should be using database transactions throughout your application. See [Why is concurrency control needed?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control#Why_is_concurrency_control_needed.3F)